# Windows XP will not connect to Enterprise Wireless

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, radius, windows-xp, 802.1, nps

We run a Radius server (Windows Server 2008 R2 running NPS). My goal is to push out GPOs to wireless users with the network information. I am successfully doing this with Windows 7 clients, iOS clients, and Android clients, but Windows XP is throwing fits. I am using Ubiquity UniFi APs: http://www.ubnt.com/unifi

When creating the GPOs for this, I mirrored all of the settings I used for Vista and W7 clients to the settings for my XP clients, but XP will not connect. I am not given any error messages; XP just sits there. I have also tried manually creating a wireless profile on the XP machines, and I can't get them to connect that way either. My XP test client is running SP3. I've tried everything I can think of, and I've tried to find info online.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: WinXP WPA2 Updated? http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1974

Comment: Have you looked in the event log? There should definitely be errors/warnings there.

Comment: I can't apply the update because I am already running SP3. When trying to install, it says the service pack I am running is newer than the update. So, I assume that hot fix was part of the service pack.

Comment: The event log on the NPS server isn't logging anything.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a problem with the device driver. Windows wasn't showing WPA2 as an option in the wireless setup. I uninstalled the wireless adapter in Device Manager and let Windows recognize and reinstall it. All is well now.

Thanks to all for your help!
Luke

Comment: Great to hear you've resolved this. Be sure to mark your answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Add the Machine Certificate of the NPS Server to the trusted List, then also XP will join :-)
...or the Certificate you are using in NPS... look it up, you can configure it.

Comment: Do **not** post links advertising your site/business in answers. That's what you have a profile for. If you post good answers, people will view it. If you post rubbish that doesn't answer questions (like this), people won't.

Comment: I unchecked the option to 'validate certificate.' If that is unchecked, I don't need to add the certificate do I?